# C#.Net Messages are going to spam folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, spam

I am sending email from my ASP.net web application.

The mails are sending successfully with out fail but most of them are going to spam folder.

Please help me to over come spam filter.

My Send Mail code

```
public void SendMail(string FromAddress, string ToAddress, string Subject, string BodyText)
    {
        MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();

        mailMsg.From = new MailAddress(FromAddress,"My Name");
        mailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(ToAddress));
        mailMsg.Subject = Subject;
        mailMsg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

        System.Net.Mail.AlternateView plainView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString
        (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(BodyText, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty), null, "text/plain");
        System.Net.Mail.AlternateView htmlView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(BodyText, null, "text/html");

        mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
        mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

        // Smtp configuration
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.mysite.com";

        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(FromAddress, "password");
        smtp.EnableSsl = false;
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(mailMsg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with .NET or C#. What's the content of those messages?

Comment: Agree: This is content related. Content seem to be empty when i look at the code...

Comment: Have you looked at the headers of the messages in the spam folder? There might be classification headers added that explains why it was marked as spam. Are you sending from an email address that has a valid, existing, email domain?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146327/mail-arrives-in-spam

Comment: You need to post the received full message source to understand the reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing that stands out is that you are never setting the body. I would remove this line:

```
// Remove the html alternate view
mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

And try the following (Untested):

```
// Set the html view to be the default view, leaving the plain text view as the only alternative view
mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMsg.Body = htmlView;
```

Comment: That wouldn't help keeping the mails out of the spam folder. On the contrary, rather.

Comment: @DanielFischer, correct, in a sense. It all depends on the content of the message. Not setting the body won't help the situation much though (I assume)

Comment: this doesn't help me. also content is not the problem for me

Answer (score 4):

Mails are often marked as spam due to special words in the subject, the sender's domain or the content of the mail or the attaches. So I don't think it has anything to do with the sending mechanism like c# or .NET

Answer (score 1):

There are a whole number of reasons why your email may be marked as spam. [This](http://forums.phplist.com/viewtopic.php?t=21772) is a good list of how to try to avoid having your emails marked as spam. In my experience though it has been wasier to use a service such as [AuthSMTP](http://www.authsmtp.com/) instead.