# C# SmtpClient google mail spam folder

Tags: c#, .net, email, gmail

I send a simple email but it gets into googlemails spam folder. This is not the case for other e-mail accounts. Any ideas?

```
   MailMessage Email = new MailMessage();
   Email.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
   Email.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
   Email.From = new MailAddress(appSettings.MailSender);
   Email.To.Add(empfaenger);
   Email.Subject = "mytitle";
   Email.Body = "Plaintext";
   Email.IsBodyHtml = false;

   SmtpClient MailClient = new SmtpClient(appSettings.MailServer,25);
   MailClient.Timeout = 300000;
   MailClient.EnableSsl = true;
   MailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(appSettings.MailUser, appSettings.MailPass);
   MailClient.SendAsync(Email, null);
```

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380105/how-to-send-email-without-go-to-spam-mail

Comment: i checked this already. This is no solution.

Comment: this is content and/or sender-recipient related. see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079902/c-net-messages-are-going-to-spam-folder

Comment: this doesn't help me. also content is not the problem for me, same email goes through via webserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out that the internet provider blocked the mailserver.